# Как крутить модель объекта не задевая его компонентов?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

У меня есть объект, на котором висят 2 коллайдера. Как мне крутить 3д модель так, чтобы коллайдеры оставались на своих позициях?

Comment: А зачем это нужно?

Comment: А зачем нужно, например: я хочу, чтобы модель производила анимацию, коллайдеры ловили объекты, которые в той области, где они были установлены в самом начале

Answer (score 4, accepted):

создаешь пустой обьект, на нем размещаешь коллайдер

внутри этого обьекта находится второй обьект у которого уже есть меш рендерер.

В таком случае ты крутишь внутренний с мешем, а внешний с коллайдером остается неподвижным.