# Как убрать привязку к положению родителя?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно сделать один объект родителем другого, чтоб при удалении они оба удалялись. Но проблема в том, что ребенок привязывается к положению и вращению родителя, а мне это не нужно. Надо просто, чтобы объект был привязан к другому и все, без привязки положения и вращения

Comment: Вопрос слишком обфусцирован. Можете привести конкретный пример, как это должно работать? Быть может пример кода и/или скриншоты есть?

Comment: Кода нет. Сейчас не дома. Есть объект 1 со спрайтом. Также есть другой объект 2 со спрайтом. Когда я добавляю объект 1 как родитель объекта 2, то объект 2 принимает непонятное положение и вращение, которое никак ему не задавалось. Если прокрутить и повращать объект 1, то и объект 2 будет тоже непонятно крутиться и вращаться. Как этого можно избежать. Нужно, чтобы объект 2 всегда имел свое положение и вращение

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1299240/373567 оно?

Comment: Вопрос следующий: как привязать объект, что бы он не был привязан? Ответ: нам всем ужасно душно и жарко, но это не повод сходить с ума.

Comment: Aepot да в целом оно. Бесит, что многое в юнити делается через какие то непонятные кастыли. Неужели нельзя было просто добавить угалочку, не привязывать к позиции.

Comment: Можно тогда что то типа родителя сделать, просто если я удаляю один объект, то удаляется и второй который надо? Может и не надо тогда с этим париться

Comment: Ваша ошибка в `Мне нужно сделать один объект родителем другого`. Не нужно! Не придется мучительно лечить последствия стрельбы себе в ноги `непонятными костылями`.

Answer (score 0):

Просто удаляйте 2 объекта, для этого можете использовать FindGameObject.

Comment: А если эти объекты создаются как клоны, и удаляю я объект мышкой, и также должен удаляться объект ниже этого

Comment: @Влад Тогда можете создать переменную и в старт устанавливать её на позицию  объекта, и в Update или FixedUpdate, приравнивать позицию к этой переменной.